# Swap drive not operating correctly

Tags: lubuntu, swap

At first, I started seeing the warning signs. The halting pages. The molasses speed of the windows closing. The pictures not rendering. Then, I took action.

Recently I added a swap drive to my computer.

For a while, everything was good. Unicorns frolicked among the new bits and bytes resplendent on the shiny metal platter known as my swap drive.

---

Today, I opened Chromium, and got  on the 7th tab (start.csail.mit.edu) "He's dead, Jim!". This used to happen before I added my swap drive, but now I thought that it wouldn't happen because I added more memory.

I fear for the safety of the unicorns. Please help me make my swap drive work again.

---

As a side note, here is the result of `cat /proc/swaps`:

```
Filename        Type            Size        Used      Priority
/dev/sda5      partition        39075836    213896    -1
```

Result of `free`:

```
                       total      used       free     shared    buffers    cached
Mem:                   507472     330792     176680   0         6208       71252
-/+ buffers/cache:     253332     254140
```

Result of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       147G  8.9G  130G   7% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            240M   12K  240M   1% /dev
tmpfs            50M  824K   49M   2% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            248M  208K  248M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Comment: Post these above also df -h and post free to see swap & memory use.

Comment: Posted. Sorry for the delay, I had to wait for the problem to crop up again.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem but I'm sure that you should not worry about the Swap, as it is not the issue.. You can open **System Monitor** and under `Resources` tab you can see the history of **Swap** being used. You'll get that actually swap was hardly used.

Comment: I am using lubuntu. I cannot use System Monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that it took a good 10 seconds for the swap drive to check in when the computer was booting up. This meant that Chrome would overload the RAM because of the memory space.

All in all, the unicorns just take a little while to get running and to spin the hard drive disk.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Side there is no Swap has been on now , Your df -h output Doesn't have a SWAP ,

Follow this and u can get fix

[Swap drive not turning on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359238/swap-drive-not-turning-on-when-i-log-in/359242#359242)

Edit your vim /etc/fstab

And add the swap fstab entry reboot and check using df -h

Here is my answer for how to check swap and how to on the Swap

[Swap on and status](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359258/swap-not-available-on-system-monitor/359261#359261)